Проблема с изменением размера окна в WinForms: мерцание и рассыпание на полоски при перетаскивании рамки
Я работаю над проектом в WinForms и столкнулся с проблемой при попытке изменить внешний вид окна. В частности, я хотел создать собственную рамку окна, используя элемент управления Panel. Для этого я написал код, который изменяет ширину окна при перетаскивании правой границы рамки.
Код работает, но при перетаскивании рамки всё окно на мгновение рассыпается на полоски. Это выглядит очень некрасиво и мешает пользователю.
Я ищу способ исправить эту проблему и сделать изменение размера окна более плавным и эстетичным. Также буду благодарен за любые советы по альтернативным способам реализации этой задачи.
Вот фрагменты кода:
Создаю правую границу окна
Panel rightPanel = new Panel();

rightPanel.BackColor = borderColor;
rightPanel.Width = 5;
rightPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
Controls.Add(rightPanel);
rightPanel.Visible = true;

rightPanel.MouseMove += rightPanel_MouseMove;

Прописываю ей логику
private void rightPanel_MouseMove(object? sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        //this. = MousePosition.X;
        this.Width = MousePosition.X - this.Location.X;
    }
}


Возможно поможет включение двойной буферизации (DoubleBuffered).

Двойная буферизация не помогла, увы. Думаю тогда переписать проект на wpf или на .net 4.8, как думаете, есть ли в этом смысл? Я имею ввиду, поможет ли это решить проблему (хотя уже не допустить причины этой проблемы)

переписать ... на .net 4.8 - А сейчас у вас какая версия дотнета: 2.0? О_о

Что сказать что-то определённое, нужно видеть больше кода. Никому не ведомо, как и что вы делаете. Нужен код, чтобы любой желающий мог его скопипастить и запустить у себя. Только не надо ссылок на гитхаб или яндекс-диск!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3718648/5045688 - нэ?

Ахахах, да не, на 8.0 писал
Просто где-то цепанул краем глаза этот варик
В целом вы подкинули мне решение проблемы, за что большое спасибо
Если не трудно, не могли бы вы посоветовать, как сюда скидывать свой код, если он довольно объёмный и раскидан по файлам и директориям?

Никак, можно важное оформить в тексте вопроса, а дополнительно дать например ссылку на гитхаб.
